# How do I quit Meta?

Tags: support, meta, deleted-users

I want to remove my account from Meta. How can I do that?

Comment: Just... stop coming here?

Comment: Well, I want to wipe the history of hateful comments on my posts on meta and the posts themselves and in general disassociate myself from the meta community. Isn't there a right to be forgotten on here? :)

Comment: You can have the posts disassociated from your account, delete them if they don't have upvoted or multiple answers, flag offensive or unhelpful comments; same stuff you usually can.

Comment: Delete the entire parent community and start over.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To clarify because there's a lot of misinformation here: We *can* delete your Meta profile only. However:

1. It is still subject to the 24-hour countdown period before the deletion occurs, like on main sites.
2. Deleting your Meta profile is a bit of a fruitless effort because it is always automatically recreated for you the moment you visit Meta for any reason while logged into your main account. And no, there is no way to prevent that automatic creation from occurring.

If you don't want to be associated with specific questions, request disassociation using the [contact us form](/contact). Otherwise, your only option is to just not visit, or don't do anything if you have to visit. We're not going to *keep deleting* your profile here every time it gets recreated for you. By the same token, don't go losing your temper here every day and then asking for disassociation - there's a more expedient solution to such problems that will eventually occur to us.

Comment: If he has his meta account deleted, and then re-visits meta, will the newly created account have all his old content from before it was deleted?

Comment: @TylerH No. Posts get anonymized the same way they do on main sites. But disassociating is plain faster than going through the entire deletion process if that's the true desire.

Comment: @animuson There's one caveat: if any of the posts were migrated to meta, they'll get remapped to the new account all over again. (This is another reason to disassociate rather than delete the user.)

Answer (score 18):

Click the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page and send us a request for deletion.

Given meta deletion is so unusual, you'll have to choose "Other" and write out what you want; if you choose "I need to delete my user profile", it'll just give you an error.

Comment: This is like a [javascript] question, 4 answers within a minute of eachother.

Comment: If there's one thing meta users know like the backs of their hands, it's rage quits.

Comment: For the sake of reference: [List of already deleted ragequits mixed with downvote rants (requires that your username ends with a diamond)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvotes+deleted%3A1+score%3A...-10)

Answer (score 2):

<s>The only way I can think of to remove your Meta Stack Overflow account is to delete your Stack Overflow account- The two are tied together and I'm unsure if the team can delete one but not the other.</s> [Two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337886/2607247) [members](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337882/2607247) of the Stack Overflow team have stated that this is incorrect.

To hopefully address a little of why you'd like your Meta account removed:

Meta is a bit different of a beast than Stack Overflow Main. Questions and answers tend to get more attention, as less questions hit Meta per day. There's also a smaller group of frequent users on Meta than Main. If your question is poorly researched, a duplicate, or a rant, it is incredibly likely to be found out.

If you wish to delete your Meta account because of the downvotes on three of your four (visible) Meta questions, I really wouldn't worry about it. Downvotes on Meta are different. They can mean the same things they mean on Main, but they can also be opinions of the thought, feature, or premise of the post. This is especially true of feature requests, but the mentality does extend to anything that suggest a feature or has a premise a lot of users (dis)agree with.

Under the assumption that you do not want to delete your account, I would suggest not contributing to Meta for a while. If you do want to contribute in the future, or think that you'll want to, perhaps lurk on Meta in the intervening time. It can help you not only get a feel for the differences between the two sites, but also help you see what helps make good posts on Meta.