# Is there any way I can turn Stack Overflow Meta off?

Tags: support, meta

<sub>This question is inspired (some might argue it is a blatant copy) by [this deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407033) by user [Rounin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3897775/rounin)</sub>

---

I like Stack Overflow.

Actually I love it.

I find Stack Overflow a wonderfully collaborative, educational site where people can learn from and teach each other and share knowledge with each other.

---

I don't like Stack Overflow Meta.

I find Stack Overflow Meta an attention drain that consumes too much time of my precious day.

---

I would like to divorce my experience of Stack Overflow from my experience of Stack Overflow Meta.

If I can do that by cutting Stack Overflow Meta out of my life entirely, all the better.

If my only option is to grit my teeth and ignore the latter, then I'll do that.

I was wondering if there is an option to turn Meta off for me. I've found [Provide a setting to hide "Featured on Meta" posts in the Community Bulletin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251920) but that is only a partial solution. I'm still two clicks away from another lost hour. Nor does [How do I quit Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337880) really offer a viable solution.

*How can I turn Stack Overflow Meta off, please?*

Comment: Did Rounin ask you to repost this on his behalf? I was going to undelete his question tbh - seeing this now has only solidified my decision to do so. (I say this knowing I've [done exactly the same thing before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332792/should-i-downvote-a-self-answer-if-it-doesnt-work-for-me)...)

Comment: You cannot. Once you've visited it, it will forever remain a part of your life.

Comment: IIUC, this version of the question is asking how to block/ignore a site? If so, that doesn't seem to have anything to do with MSO in particular. This question seems more on-topic on the Main site, or probably SuperUser.

Comment: @cigien: Why can't it be specific to SO/MSO? If you really wanted to generalize it, you could generalize it to an MSE question asking, "Can I turn off a per-site meta?"

Comment: @BoltClock no, I didn't had the impression the OP and myself were on speaking terms. It was my decision to go forward with this as I felt there was some merit in that question. Open for suggestions how you want to go forward.

Comment: @BoltClock Hmm, is turning off a per-site meta any different than turning off some other site? I suppose an answer like "There's no built in way" would be fine (as already posted).

Comment: @rene: You know what, the original question's got too many downvotes. Having said that I'm far more sympathetic to the tone OP used, especially when Meta's fixation on that, as well as some of the responses there... are kinda part of the problem.

Comment: @cigien: Does it have to be? I don't see why we have to go out of our way to distill every question to its lowest common denominator. If I have a question about using Stack Overflow, The Internet for Dummies isn't going to be the first place I look.

Comment: You can close the tab any time you want, but you can never leave

Comment: @Nick - seems like the userscript relies on `@match` directive, but I am not sure what's the point in testing for `meta` in the `href` property - Scratte?

Comment: @OlegValter Yes, I did miss that, but that means it'll only block SO meta :p

Comment: @OlegValter There's a  [Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends) for userscripts :)

Comment: I understand the downvotes on the original question and I disagree (mostly) with how the OP described meta. But closing the post as unclear and deleting it within minutes?! Seriously? Just why? What exactly was unclear about the post? Don't you see how this kind of proves his point? How ironic!

Comment: @41686d6564 what else had you hoped for? That we let it shine as an prime example of how you can interact with meta and meta with you? At best it shows an exchange of idea / opinions and thoughts we don't prefer having more of. If the OP doesn't take the opportunity to bring a post down to its bare essentials without insulting their peers I see no reason to keep that around. What really is ironic they came to Meta to become one of the clique. They could have used Contact Us as they after all sought help from SE Executives, not the crowd here.

Comment: Because, not least, I would hope to see SE Executives play a more active role in Meta (and in Stack Overflow, generally). Where I have used a word such as _ungenerous_ it is certainly not meant as some kind of provocative insult. It is meant as a literal description of what I see, regularly, in meta which often appears to approximate a desert of emotional intelligence. Occasionally there is an oasis. You reference _the clique_ and _the crowd_. These terms already seem like red flags.

Comment: @OlegValter - Honestly, you're not missing very much. The question I posted was almost exactly the same as what **rene** posted above (word for word), except for one short paragraph in which I was more direct about what I regard as some of the more regrettable behaviours of some members of the community here in SO Meta. I used to encounter the same sort of toxicity on Facebook. In the end the easiest solution was to leave Facebook. I've really enjoyed not being on FB for the last year and a quarter since I left. I concluded that cutting SO Meta out of my life would be an equally good move.

Comment: @Rounin I'm considering to follow your footsteps...

Comment: @Rounin - well, not going to insist, thanks for responding anyway. Re: leave - to each their own, I guess. I enjoy Meta quite a lot but understand if someone considers it no longer (or ever) their cup of tea. Take care!

Comment: @Oleg [Here's a screenshot of the deleted post](https://i.imgur.com/3XQF0lz.png).

Comment: @Rounin: FWIW, I just about draw the line before "misanthropic", which you've used in *multiple questions* during your time here - I can agree with all the other descriptors you used in your original question, but that one in particular tends to make folks really hard to take seriously. As for your original question I think you just used too many descriptors (and that, to me, is how it came off as provocative). There didn't need to be a paragraph full of the things - probably one or two would've been enough to get your point across. I've been there myself, so I know what it's like.

Comment: Conceded @BoltClock. What particularly riled me yesterday was reading a Meta Post infused with what came across as a pretty self-righteous tone which declared - amongst other things - that some questions were less worthy than others. This failed to appreciate - and this appears to be a hallmark of SO Meta - that people who don't write the best questions (or answers) need be guided supportively and sympathetically rather than hounded out of town. [1/2]

Comment: I constantly get the impression that those who most strongly advocate _their_ vision of Stack Overflow identify as some kind of _elite corps_ of programmers and don't want people who they regard as _not in their gang_ to be contributing to Stack Overflow. I am not a programmer, so to me, this whole atttitude comes across as pretty tribal and pretty hostile. For me, Stack Overflow, is about _programming_, not about _being a programmer_ (or a _brogrammer_). That's a subtle distinction, but it's that not subtle. Whenever SO isn't welcoming to people who aren't programmers, it bothers me. [2/2]

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly useful resource - a really amazing asset to the web. But the specific group of people who constantly talk _prescriptively_ about what Stack Overflow can and cannot be - as if what they use the platform for has validity, but no-one who uses it in a different way has a legitimate right to be here - feel like a cancer which damage what is otherwise one of the best sites on the web. [3/2]

Comment: I can mostly avoid these people if I stay away from Meta. I am afraid that the people responsible for the toxicity won't recognise it, because to them it isn't toxic - it's exciting because it's all about them and it excludes people who aren't them. [4/2]

Comment: @Rounin: Yeah, I completely agree. The other mods and CMs can attest to an outburst I had in private just last week, also in response to some behavior on meta (albeit behavior not representative of everyone here, it's still a real problem that needs to be acknowledged). That was partially my fault though - I tend to bottle up my emotions around these things, and don't have a very good outlet for them.

Comment: @Rounin: The irony is that you've now been provided with several ways to stay out of Meta, yet you consistently return here to state how much you hate the regulars on here. How "toxic" they are, how much they're not worthy of your appreciation. Mate, if you come in here with a ___constructive___ attitude, you'll get constructive feedback in return. I've never, _ever_ seen you write in a ___constructive___ manner.

Comment: I wondered how long it would be before someone reeled out that chestnut. Yes, I am returning. To this page only. No other page on Meta. If my bookmarklet strategy continues to work successfully, you won't be seeing me on any other page on Meta in future either. What a relief for both of us. If you want to see constructive attitudes, start by adopting a constructive attitude to all the non-programmers on Stack Overflow. Let's see if they're worthy of _your_ appreciation.

Comment: But dear @Cerbrus it is the quality that counts, not the quantity ...

Comment: Here's the issue: _"Help them understand how the site works"_ < This dynamic is - needs to be - more of a give and take than some are prepared to accommodate themselves to. Stack Overflow can be pretty unyielding, pretty uncompromising. Some individuals will - I regretfully conclude - never understand this. Are you really here to help _all_ users? Or just all users who can easily metamorphose into a one-size, fits-all, standard-SO-User model? Some people might write 5-6 bad questions before they start to get the hang of it all. They aren't less worthy than others who "get it" immediately.

Comment: @Rounin: We can't accommodate _everyone_. It's literally impossible on a site this large. Even if you were to get rid of all rules, that would be excluding people. Rene: I'm pretty sure the quality of my answers is very acceptable :D

Comment: Hey folks, let's keep the tone civil and on-topic. Cleaned some irrelevant comments out and there's way too many comment flags going on.

Comment: @Rounin "Stack Overflow can be pretty unyielding, pretty uncompromising. Some individuals will - I regretfully conclude - never understand this. " - that isn't Stack Overflow's problem, nor is it a problem specific to Stack Overflow. Some users get the hang of things eventually, but that's largely a result of trial, error, and actually using common sense and trying to understand the feedback received. Your comment, however, is attacking intentions, but you're forgetting that not everyone can be helped, or wants help. They want a quick answer usually without doing research, and then kthxbye.

Comment: Getting people onboarded has always been a problem, but not because we're trying to push people out, or because we're trying to push out new coders, but because we haven't had the right learning tools, and some people refuse to read the stuff available to them. *That is not our fault*. Even if we had a super "soft" onboarding process, I guarantee you a decent chunk of people would blatantly ignore it and still post trash. _That_ is the part of the equation you've left out. You can't help or onboard people who don't care.

Comment: Yes. You make several entirely fair points, @Zoe. Though, rather than how users treat Stack Overflow, I am much _more_ concerned about how Stack Overflow treats users. (I find this is what's most lacking amongst those who most enthusiastically race to defend SO - they fail to comprehend that their priority ought to be to police their own conduct before they consider policing the conduct of others.) [1/3]

Comment: Stack Overflow as an entirety doesn't treat new users that poorly. If you've ever spent any substantial time in moderation, you'd quickly notice a pattern of new users lashing out against people doing moderation, often in a way that's a direct violation of the code of conduct and just common decency in general. I'm not racing to defend SO by the way, I'm highly aware there's several problems, but I'm not gonna let you just blame the core users when blame is a two-way street. There's more layers than just SO or just new users - it's a compound of both, but only one has to take the blame (SO)

Comment: Re: _"that isn't Stack Overflow's problem"_ I'd contend that Stack Overflow's remarkable rigidity / inability to comprehend cultures other than its own absolutely _is_ this platform's problem. Re: _"That is not our fault"_ I'd contend that failing to acculturate people absolutely is our fault. Stack Overflow has an idiosyncratic, bordering on abnormal, culture of conduct. It's incumbent upon any SO user who has been here a couple of years to recognise that and to see how frankly _weird_ it is to new users who may only have been around for a couple of weeks, months or even a year or two. [2/3]

Comment: "I'd contend that Stack Overflow's remarkable rigidity / inability to comprehend cultures other than its own absolutely is this platform's problem" - that's because we don't care about cultures. SO has a culture because it automatically gets one when there's people involved. There's no one denying that other interaction styles exist, but it's not nearly as rigid as you claim. We have a set of rules, just like every other major site on the web (excluding anarchy sites/servers), and every organized country on the planet. What're you trying to say here though? That we fail to bring people in?

Comment: We're not denying other cultures in any meaning of the word even if we have certain rules on interactions, but that has nothing to do with rigidity or an inability to comprehend other cultures. Acceptance of cultures (again, in any meaning of the word) has nothing to do with the Q&A anyway, but rather certain interactions.

Comment: Re: _"some people refuse to read the stuff available to them"_ This is not the first time I've seen this defence. I don't for a moment to expect _everyone_ on SO to be working on the web, nor to have done work which falls under the umbrella of _Usability_. Consequently, I don't expect everyone here to have read Steve Krug's seminal _"Don't Make Me Think"_. But it _ought_ to be pretty widely known tenet of usability that users don't read, will not read written instructions. Most of the time SO Meta behaves like it's never heard of this principle. And yet many of us work on the web (?) [3/3]

Comment: " I don't for a moment to expect everyone on SO to be working on the web" - what does this have to do with anything? The asking page has several in-your-face popups, there's a notification informing you about a tour, and there's an entire help center with frequently asked questions - that's prior to mentioning meta. We're not talking about a lot of effort here, and it has absolutely nothing to do with whatever you mean by "working on the web".

Comment: For clarification: when I use the word _culture_ I am referring to _user culture_. I'm talking about **usability** and **user experience**.

Comment: " Consequently, I don't expect everyone here to have read Steve Krug's seminal "Don't Make Me Think"" - again, what's your point? I'm talking about help center resources and in general other resources that are a part of Stack Overflow. It's not unreasonable to expect people to try to get familiar with the site by reading a few available resources before starting.

Comment: Usability and user experience have absolutely nothing to do with culture, nor is it a word you can use to express those two topics. "But it ought to be pretty widely known tenet of usability that users don't read, will not read written instructions. Most of the time SO Meta behaves like it's never heard of this principle. And yet many of us work on the web" - There's also banner blindness, but you can't blame the party with actual resources available just because people don't want to read. Every single user has the opportunity to make it on SO, but that doesn't make it an automatic [1/2]

Comment: right for everyone to get without doing work or putting in an effort to understand the site. It's perfectly possible to make it on SO without reading anything, but most people who actually get anywhere do so because they try to understand the system, rather than assigning blame to SO (and/or its core users) when they inevitably do something we've documented _several_ times as not being okay. If you're completely going to disregard that new users also have a certain responsibility, then we're done here.

Comment: That last bit though, someone phrased it slightly better than me in a parallel discussion - "just how entitled does one have to be to think that the rules will change because they joined". That's an incredibly good question, and one I dare you to answer. Again, it's not just the responsibility of SO when a new user joins. There's SO (providing the systems), the community (providing moderation), and the actual joining user. If the joining user refuses to try to participate in a proper manner, that's not automatically SO's fault, nor is it the "user culture" (you're abusing the English language

Comment: at this point) that's to blame. Again, there are a LOT of resources on and off SO on how you interact with SO, how you ask good questions, how you write good answers, what's on-topic, and what's not. If someone refuses to read, it's on them. If there's a design problem, it's on SO. It could even be both at once -- it's nowhere near as single-sided as you seem to think it is, and honestly, the sooner you realize that, the better.

Comment: Re: _"Usability and user experience have absolutely nothing to do with culture, nor is it a word you can use to express those two topics."_ I'm not clear what you mean by this. SO has a very distinctive user-culture (highly unusual compared to most websites) and failing to fit in quickly with the user-culture strongly impacts on an SO user's experience. It is quick to punish, to exclude and to alienate. Woe betide you make a rookie mistake like linking to a technically 100% accurate page on W3Schools. Woe betide you venture to ask for help in your question title using the wrong form of words.

Comment: Oh god what did I just come back to...

Comment: Sorry BoltClock :) @Rounin "highly unusual compared to most websites" - (x) doubt. Every single site on the web has a culture. "It is quick to punish, to exclude and to alienate" - I've experienced the _exact_ opposite, and that's in spite of having questions closed and answers deleted. "Woe betide you make a rookie mistake like linking to a technically 100% accurate page on W3Schools" (I swear you're making an effort to find as obscure words as possible, but) that's a JS-specific culture, and not everyone on the entire site agrees. It's also not exclusive to SO

Comment: You've completely lost me regarding your assertions to culture, @Zoe. Are you suggesting that Stack Overflow does not have a community of users with a culture? I'd posit that of all sites on the web - including Wikipedia - SO has one of the strongest user-community-cultures anywhere.

Comment: You can base a whole lot of your anti-SO opinions on your personal experience and interpretation, but that's just your experience, @Rounin. Meanwhile, a _humongous_ amount of users are successfully asking and answering questions on SO. You're focusing _exclusively_ on the negative interpretations of events. I don't see any willingness to listen to the other side of the story. This has been a monologue from the start.

Comment: @Rounin I just said every single site has a culture, but I strongly disagree with your observations and assertions about its culture. Notably the W3Schools argument - that's a JS core thing that has nothing to do with SO (you can find it elsewhere, including with people who don't have accounts on SO), because W3Schools has historically struggled with accuracy of their content. Your definition of "strongest" relies purely on your own experiences - I've seen substantially stronger cultures, and if you want examples, visit 4chan or certain subreddits

Comment: My experience on Stack Overflow is generally good, thanks, @Cerbrus. I do my best to help a lot of people and I'm grateful that a lot of people appreciate the help that I'm fortunate enough to be able to give them. I also ask questions and I'm very grateful to the SO users who help me with those questions. It's all pretty positive.

Comment: @BoltClock - an observation: these blowups tend to happen on Friday :)

Comment: Would adding `127.0.0.1 meta.stackoverflow.com` to the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) be within the range of acceptable answers?

Comment: As if driven to make my point for me, when I asked the original question, the same thought police raced to tear me apart for asking if it's possible have a Stack Overflow account which doesn't constantly advertise meta in the right-hand sidebar. Confirming, fairly unambiguously, that if you don't think like them, you probably have no business being on SO at all. I guess the SO Execs would probably prefer these zealots don't persist in making new users (and everyone else) feel unwelcome, but maybe they're a cheap alternative to having an agency design top-class gamified induction for new users.

Comment: Never mind. I'm sure I'm not the only person who thinks that Stack Overflow is "better without meta". I'm also certain that I'm not the only individual (the existence of this page is strong evidence) who feels that - wherever you stand with regard to meta - it ought to be entirely legitimate to voice that opinion without being shot down nearly immediately. My preferred configuration would be: meta for those who want it, no meta for those who don't. In the meantime I'll continue with my Bookmarklet which does the job and I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: Ya know, those "Thought police" comments of yours aren't helping your case. They just make you sound like someone that really isn't interested in all of the helpful answers you've gotten there. The reason you were getting "torn apart" was because you just dumped a rant on Meta. That's unacceptable.

Comment: You've missed the point. I'll repeat what I last wrote: My preferred configuration would be meta for those who want it, no meta for those who don't. Until SO introduces that as an option, I'll continue to use my Bookmarklet. I'll live in hope that meta will learn to develop a more emotionally intelligent culture, more capable of assessing context, more focused on helping people and less focused on refereeing them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, you need to arrange a visit to the Stack Exchange server room (suggestions on various nefarious ways to do this may appear in the comments).

When you get there, look for one of these …

[image]

… that has "meta.stackoverflow.com" written near it. Then … well, just make sure you're wearing thick rubber gloves.

Comment: I'm looking for a mousetrap?

Comment: Exterminating the mice that power the servers might also work?

Comment: That is a "farmer's switch" (I couldn't find a reference - it is extremely search unfriendly) - it doesn't do anything (all plastic and no connected wires).

Comment: @PeterMortensen still hilarious though. I highly doubt adrian mole could get an actual picture of the server switch that powers meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This is by far the funniest answer I have ever seen.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I suspect this particular one flips the lightswitch that it's attached to :-)

Answer (score 30):

There's no built-in way to turn Meta off.

Just don't visit it.
You need to deliberately click a meta link to end up on the site... Just don't do that.

If you really want to, you could block Meta links with an adblocker, block the domain in your host file, or even block it on DNS level.

Answer (score 9):

Well - to be fair, that's a significant issue with meta for even those of us who love it. it *can* be a time sink and for many not always healthy.

That said - depending on your self control levels, there's lots of ways to block meta from your life. A good many number of people don't ever come to meta, or even know it exists. I suppose its too late for that at this point.

I'd suggest the 'lightest' approach first - assuming you're not going out of the way to go to meta, you could block the `##.m0.p0.d-block` element with your adblock of choice. This hides the meta side bar.

A more heavy handed approach might be to block MSO (and/or MSE subdomains), either crudely with hosts.txt or at a local domain name resolution service.

I'd say though - *fundamentally* there's a good many toxic places on the internet, and your ability to avoid them may vary.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like to divorce my experience of Stack Overflow from my experience of Stack Overflow Meta.

This method works very well:

Just re-visit [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) old, depressing thread and read it all again on regular basis. I have significantly and permanently lost interest in checking meta and participating since those events.

It also does wonders against any urge you have to help with review queues, user moderation, tag burnination and other such unpaid busy-work. I'm also down to just a few reviews/month where I used to do hundreds.

Comment: The situation illustrated in the question is that the user _already_ dislikes Meta. This answer doesn't help "turn off" meta...

Comment: @Cerbrus The OP is essentially asking how to cure their addiction. This worked very well for me. And I don't even dislike meta as such.

Comment: In the spirit of the source question, I don't think this is about a addiction, more about being unable to ignore notifications / questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus I disagree, everything in the question seems to be about dealing with an uncontrolled addiction. If you are addicted to alcohol, then the solution isn't to find a way to block your friends' requests to go out and grab a beer, or to block your credit card from working at certain locations. Now what if you could instead find a way to completely lose your taste for it?

Comment: Just read the original question...

Comment: @Cerbrus Which I of course did. Twice actually.

Comment: Then we'll just have to disagree

Comment: @Lundin is right. I am drawn in to Meta against my better nature. Then I get riled because I am, if you like, _a bad fit_ for a Meta, because I disagree, sometimes very strongly, with what I regard as a pretty exclusive set of views paraded by no small number of Meta regulars. The easiest solution for me is to lock myself out of Meta and forget it ever exists. Lundin perceived the issue and articulated it better than I did.

Comment: _"<...> Then I get riled because I am, if you like, a bad fit for a Meta, because I disagree, sometimes very strongly, with the views of Meta regulars."_ There, same message, sans the aggressive language and name-calling. The reason you're consistently clashing with the "Meta crowd" is because you're consistently expressing your disagreement in a aggressive or even offensive manner. If you can disagree politely, and you'll find Meta can be a very constructive place.

Comment: @Cerbrus - The reason I clash with the "Meta crowd" is because it very much comes across as "a crowd" - and that's a pretty strong red flag for me. I was always taught that one should stand up to bullies, so, yes, where I see bullying behaviour, I will stand up to them. If there are individuals on Meta who want to tear into Stack Overflow users who aren't experienced in Stack Overflow communication culture or in programming, I'm happy to tear back into those individuals. There is a lot of bullying behaviour on Stack Overflow - and a culture of groupthink. This is particularly evident in Meta.

Comment: There you go again. ___Immediately___ on the offense. _"They're a crowd! They have to be taken down!"_ Mate, the "fight" you're mentioning consistently starts at your end. Just look at the language you're using here... _"Tear into them"_ _"bullying"_, _"groupthink"_, and you wonder why you don't get along with the regulars.

Comment: Yes, yes. I get your point. You're entitled to give it out. But you don't like taking it. If you genuninely believe that Stack Overflow is wonderfully warm and welcoming place for all, how do you account for all the people (both here and former members) who have given up because of the way the culture here can (so often) turn toxic so rapidly? Rather than explain that, why don't you move on to gaslighting individuals who dare to speak up about the toxicity? It's their fault, right?

Comment: Toxicity is a two-way street. I think a ___very___ large portion of "Meta's toxicity" can be traced back to people coming on here _telling_ us we're toxic, whilst being completely and utterly unaware of how Meta works. They get met with answers that tell them how it is, arguably in a less-than friendly manner, and then they shoo off back to twitter or whatever to say _"See?! Meta __is__ toxic!"_ If they instead come here and _try to understand_ how Meta works, they'll get a ___massively___ different response. So yes, I'll absolutely argue that 95% of so-called "toxicity" on Meta [1/2]

Comment: ... absolutely comes from the OP barging in here with some kind of attitude. Be it about meta's culture, or how wrong it is that their question is closed, or how downvotes are so bad and a comment should be mandatory [2/2]

Comment: Alas, what Cerbrus says is accurate. The most common incidents of a poor environment on Meta come from a clash of expectations from those who start participating. Even though there sure are some weird things about Meta, such as the use of a Q&A for discussion and its associated voting culture, the biggest mistake people make is not following [Hanlon's razor](https://effectiviology.com/hanlons-razor/) and jumping to toxicity-oriented conclusions.

Comment: @E_net4: Ah, I feel better knowing, by Hanlon's razor, that Meta is mostly just stupid.

Comment: I'd rather believe that than glumly accepting it's nothing more than specialists of a certain mindset choosing not to exercise their emotional intelligence when it comes to supporting SO members who have only very modest experience of programming.

Comment: ^ which is again asserting that SO members are deliberately chasing off less experienced users, instead of trying to help them be successful on the site. That assertion is simply false.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is no denying that there's a clique of some 20 users who have a very unhealthy ratio between meta activity and main site activity. Who spend all of their days at meta and at doing meta tasks. It becomes a sub-culture, to the point where _they_ detach themselves from the culture of the actual site, stackoverflow.com, since they don't participate there. ->

Comment: Sure I agree there are people "barging in with some kind of attitude", but there are also the actual users of the actual site coming on here to discuss the real site. If they behave just as they do on the real site and that somehow becomes a problem just because they are on meta, then meta is a problem. You shouldn't need to "learn meta" if you already know SO culture. Those regulars with an unhealthy amount of meta participation vs real site participation becomes a problem. Because they just started to turn the site worse, when they become an obstacle for the actual users rather than a help.

Comment: The problem starts at the point you tell them they're _"those regulars"_. That's polarizing, unhelpful, and only fuels the flames. Nowhere are we talking about _"learn meta"_, and I have _consistently_ been arguing for _constructive_ meta contributions. The only negative experiences on here is when users come into Meta completely misunderstanding what __SO__ is about, complaining, and getting pointed to the exit because of it. I've never ever seen a constructive OP (or one that is at least willing to listen) get "abused" on Meta.

Comment: You don't remind yourself of "that time" when the elevators stopped running as a reminder as to why you only take the stairs.  Traumatic events suddenly spurning you don't actually address the end state - a chance to heal and move on from something like that.  (Hating Stack Exchange and not wanting to visit Meta Stack Overflow can be mutually exclusive.)

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna be honest - seeing something like this is cathartic.

[image]

Basically:  just don't feel obligated to always visit Meta.  You don't have to visit it, and the world isn't going to suddenly end if you don't pop by.

When [I did it last year](https://twitter.com/MakotoTheKnight/status/1271974987897831425?s=20), it was liberating.  I felt like a curse had been lifted.

If you're *really* desperate though, you could do some /etc/hosts editing (or your OS/router's equivalent) to prevent you from connecting to the site *at all*, but that's pretty drastic.

But everyone has to figure out the right way to get them to focus on the content that matters.  Sometimes, being drastic is the most effective solution.

Comment: [Give me some strength](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Zev.png) ... Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to turn Meta off.

But this bookmarklet (which may be saved to the **Bookmark Bar** and manually clicked before one's attention is drawn towards the right-hand panel) will remove all links to Meta for the duration of the rest of that page visit:

**Remove Links to Stack Overflow Meta:**

```
javascript:(()=>{[...document.querySelectorAll('[href^="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/"]')].forEach((link)=>{link.closest('li').remove()})})();
```

or, if you want to give the function in the bookmarklet an **explicit name**:

```
javascript:(function%20removeMetaLinks(){[...document.querySelectorAll('[href^="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/"]')].forEach((link)=>{link.closest('li').remove()})}());
```

Comment: You can also use a browser extension/plugin like Stylus and add some CSS rules to SO. Saves you the trouble of having to click that bookmarklet all the time.

Comment: Nice, @Ivar - that sounds even better. :-)

Comment: Or a userscript...

Comment: [Updated user script](https://pastebin.com/1nfTbY16). It will not let you see a meta page, it will remove all links to meta from the yellow box in the right sidebar and it will remove notifications from meta (like this one :-) from the inbox.

Comment: @Scratte Thank you! The big No! when you end up on a meta link is great!

Comment: @Adinia - I must warn anyone that it is still WIP, so using it requires fairly modern browsers with support of ES6 features + DOM methods like `closest` and `replaceWith` :)

Comment: User Feedback: This all seems to be working reasonably well. I don't activate the bookmarklet on every page load (which would be a hassle) but I do find that when I'm about to click a Meta Link (against my better nature), I remember to move the mouse cursor up and click the bookmarklet instead. Usually within a second or two, with the link no longer there, I've already forgotten what had caught my eye and distracted me in the first place. This is arguably a win for Meta and undoubtedly a win for me. Everyone's a winner, baby.

Comment: Reminds me there's a [new version](https://pastebin.com/XRMxuLqH) that also removes meta achievements and both "Top Meta Posts" and "Meta user"-link from user profiles :)